# Parsing numeric strings of unknown type?

Tags: c++, string, parsing, numbers

What's the best approach to parsing `std::string` to some numeric type in C++, when the target type isn't known in advance?

I've looked at [lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/synopsis.html#boost_lexical_cast.synopsis.lexical_cast), but that takes the target type as a template parameter. I could write wrapper functions that abuse this by catching `bad_lexical_cast` and returning `false`, but that seems ugly.

My input values will typically be `int` or `float` and have extremely simple formatting, but something that's flexible would be great!

Comment: I don't think catching the exception is abuse, btw, but I wouldn't write a wrapper *per type* that returns `false`, rather have a single function that tries all permitted formats. An exception is a perfectly reasonable way to indicate that a string doesn't match an expected format. It need never propagate outside the function that knows that it doesn't know the proper format, and is "taking risks" by trying a few different formats in turn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use either Boost Spirit [Numerical Parsers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric.html) or (ab)use Boost Lexicalcast.

Boost Spirit allows you fine grained control of the format accepted, see e.g.

- [RealPolicies](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric/real.html#spirit.qi.reference.numeric.real._code__phrase_role__identifier__realpolicies__phrase___code_)

Here is a quick demo, that also shows how you could detect several possible numeric input formats (*progressively*) and return the type that was matched. Of course that could be overkill, but it should demonstrate how to use Spirit further.

The demo also shows how to advance the input iterator so you can easily continue parsing where the numeric input ended.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

enum numeric_types
{
    fmt_none,
    fmt_float,
    fmt_double,
    fmt_uint,
    fmt_int,
    // fmt_hex, etc. 
};

template <typename It>
    bool is_numeric(It& f, It l, numeric_types& detected)
{
    return qi::phrase_parse(f,l,
            qi::uint_   [ qi::_val = fmt_uint   ]
          | qi::int_    [ qi::_val = fmt_int    ]
          | qi::float_  [ qi::_val = fmt_float  ]
          | qi::double_ [ qi::_val = fmt_double ]
           ,qi::space, detected);
}

template <typename It>
    bool is_numeric(It& f, It l)
{
    numeric_types detected = fmt_none;
    return is_numeric(f, l, detected);
}

int main()
{
    const std::string input = "124, -25, 582";
    std::string::const_iterator it = input.begin();

    bool ok = is_numeric(it, input.end());

    if (ok)   
    {
        std::cout << "parse success\n";
        if (it!=input.end()) 
            std::cerr << "trailing unparsed: '" << std::string(it,input.end()) << "'\n";
    }
    else 
        std::cerr << "parse failed: '" << std::string(it,input.end()) << "'\n";

    return ok? 0 : 255;
}
```

Comment: One note: using Qi you can even go one step further. Using a `boost::variant<unsigned,int,float,double>` you could not only detect the type, but also stored the parsed result in one go. I don't quite remember how to hook it up, but alternatives and variants can definitely be combined :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. I do, but that was not the question, as I read it. In fact it would probably be better to just use `qi::double_` as it should match the other options, normally. And store the parser in a static. And wrap it in `qi::wrap`... But I'm getting ahead

Answer (score 1):

When you actually parse the data to convert it, you need to know the
type in which to put the results; C++ is a statically typed language,
and there's no way around that.  If you have a string, and want to know
what type it is, using regular expressions is a simple solution:

```
"\\s*[+-]?(?:"
    "\\d+\\.\\d*(?:[Ee][+-]?\\d+)?"
    "|\\.\\d+(?:[Ee][+-]?\\d+)?"
    "|\\d+[Ee][+-]?\\d+"
")"
```

should match any possible floating point value, and:

```
"\\s*[+-]?(?:"
    "[1-9][0-9]*"
    "|0[0-7]*"
    "|0x[0-9a-fA-F]+"
)"
```

matches an integer in any base.  (Supposing the default configuration of Boost or the C++11 regular expressions.)

Comment: And be careful that those regexs match strings that are not valid (due to overflow and so on), so the parser you end up using needs to validate anyway.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes.  Once you've established what you want to convert to, you have to check that the conversion also worked.  The regular expressions only allow choosing the target type, and syntax checking; they can't help with semantic verification.